# Make Android Button Touch Sides

Tags: android, user-interface, android-button

How do I make the following type on Menu? I made it but the buttons dont touch the sides and
they leave out the background..

[image]

Help?

Comment: can you clarify your question?

Comment: It's quite unclear. What do you mean by touching the sides? Did you mean setting the "Fill parent" property to the button?

Comment: @user2578784: Check my answer. I guess it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is that you make an `ImageView` and set the background image as the one you have shown. Then handle the `onTouch` event on it according to position of touch. So by trial and error get the bounds you want for all three regions. You can get the position of click using:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = event.getX();
   int y = event.getY();
   return true;
}
```

So use the x,y coordinates you get using this code and the bounds for the 3 parts of the image you get by trial and error. Compare them and accordingly execute your code.

Hope it helps! Cheers.

Comment: This Seems Like A Very Good Answer As soon As I'm At My Laptop I'll Test It Out!